# Meaning of the a word in an magen david

Tags: hebrew, words

I have a magen david with שוי writen inside and I want to know the meaning

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could attach a photo, and / or describe the background of this item.

Comment: r6v2, Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope the community can help you get to the bottom of your mystery. I agree with @Dave that you'll get a more definitive answer if you provide a photo (there's an image upload button on the edit screen) and more details. Please consider registering your account, so the system can keep track of all your contributions.

Answer (score 9):

Could it have been ש - ד - י, and the tip dalet got scratched off? This name of God is often found on a mezuzot.

Comment: +1 for correspondence with a post on onthemainline (onthemainline.blogspot.com) from a few years ago, which includes an 18th c. sketch of a _magen David_ with the characteristic letters in the points, sharing a panel (implying some relationship?) with a _m'zuza_ whose casing clearly reads the 3 letters you suggest. In fact, the ד even looks broken at the exact spot that would make it appear as a ו or a ז next to a י!

Comment: I do not think they would put Hashem's name like that on a Magen Dovid.

Comment: Who is "they"? It is not like every Magen David goes through an approval process.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is initials of the original owner?

Comment: There are not many names that begin with a *vav*.

Comment: @Dave - One's enough, rare as it may be. Especially considering the popular monogram style of last initial in the middle (http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_7p2ZcQPaYTw/SXqc7TqWvbI/AAAAAAAAHEU/BmzNwXq5GS8/s400/interlocking-monogram-alphabet.gif) since a last name would be the most likely of the 3 to begin with _ו_. This is of course, continuing down the path of wild speculation without the benefit of a picture.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the already posted answers & comments that a picture would nice, that it may be a *dalet* rather than a *vav*, and that it may be the owner's initials. If it *is* a word שוי, then the only words I can think of with that spelling are:

- *sh'vi*, the feminine singular imperative of "to be equal" or "to be worth it" (*shin-vav-he* in *kal*), and
- *shevay*, "that woe!" (as in a sentence, "he agreed **that woe** for the loss").

Not that either makes much sense.

Comment: It is also the 3/m/s/participle for "appoint" in Aramaic.